# PHP Query Inserting Data Twice?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, fetch

I am trying to make a feature for the Mybb system going to call it social groups, so far it's been great but when I try to insert a comment in the database it inserts it twice due to the msql_fetch_array and how it works (php should fix this)

Anyway how can I get the Posts id the user is commenting on and insert it only once in the database not twice

```
<?php
require_once ("core/connection.php");
require_once ("core/group_functions.php");



    //We need to post the message update in to the database
if(isset($_POST['post_message_submit'])) {
$post_message_submit = $_POST['post_message_submit'];
$post_message = $_POST['post_message'];
    if(($post_message_submit) && ($post_message)) {

    $insert_query = $db->query("INSERT INTO " . TABLE_PREFIX . "groups_posts" . "(posted_by, group_name, post_body)
VALUES ('$mybb_username', '$get_group_url' ,'$post_message')");


    } else {
    echo "<text style='color:red;'> You Must Specify A Message</a></text>";
    }
    }



echo "
    <form action='' method='POST'>
<textarea name='post_message' id='post_message' placeholder='Whats Going On?'></textarea><br> 
       <input type='submit' name='post_message_submit' value='Post'>
        </form>

";


$fetch_index_query = $db->query("SELECT post_id,posted_by,post_body,post_active,group_name FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "groups_posts WHERE group_name='$get_group_url'");





while($fetch_index_groups_array = $db->fetch_array($fetch_index_query)) {
$post_id_row = $fetch_index_groups_array['post_id'];
$posted_by = $fetch_index_groups_array['posted_by'];
$g_name = $_fetch_index_groups_array['g_name'];
$g_body = $fetch_index_groups_array['post_body'];
echo("<br>" . "<a href=''> $posted_by </a>" . "<br>" . $gname
. "<br>____________
<br> 
<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='comment_post' placeholder='Comment then Hit Enter'>
</form>
"
);
$fetch_comments_query = $db->query("SELECT g_name,post_body,comment_by FROM spud_groups_comments WHERE post_id='$post_id_row'");
while($fetch_groups_comments = $db->fetch_array($fetch_comments_query)) {
$post_body = $fetch_groups_comments['post_body'];




echo ("<br>" . $post_body);



}
$insert_query = $db->query("INSERT INTO " . TABLE_PREFIX . "groups_posts" . "(posted_by, group_name, post_body)
VALUES ('$mybb_username', '$get_group_url' ,'$post_message')");

}

//We have done everything we need to do we can now exit and not execute anything beyond this point
exit();
?>
```

This software is going to be open source so you are really contributing to the feature by helping as I have never gone this advanced before.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the $db object? Does it only cope with a single result set by any chance?

Comment: That's the mybb forum software object it just replaces MySQL with db

Comment: You loop around $fetch_index_query and for each returned row you perform an insert. Nothing in the insert relies on anything from $fetch_index_query so there seems no point to putting the insert in the loop. But the way your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

because you are using insert query twice :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that lol I did put the query in twice for testing purposes but it did have another query to insert the comment but for some reason the fetch_array is inserting it in the database from how many comments its found (say if it's found 4 posts it will insert the comment in the database 4 times)

Comment: don't say fetch_array is inserting it, Actually u are submitting the form on the same page and the php script may run again after the form submission. So try to create files and module your project

Comment: I can try but I have taken the insert query out of the fetch_array and it only inserted once but I need with in the fetch array to get a row_id

Comment: As a good suggestion: never create dynamic forms. DO not try to include HTML in php . It is actually a bad practice. use html and php and separately as far as possible.

Comment: i'm only doing this as testing purposes but I will be separating them soon

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
            require_once ("core/connection.php");
            require_once ("core/group_functions.php");



                //We need to post the message update in to the database
            if(isset($_POST['post_message_submit'])) {
            $post_message_submit = $_POST['post_message_submit'];
            $post_message = $_POST['post_message'];
                if(($post_message_submit) && ($post_message)) {

               // $insert_query = $db->query("INSERT INTO " . TABLE_PREFIX . "groups_posts" . "(posted_by, group_name, post_body) VALUES ('$mybb_username', '$get_group_url' ,'$post_message')");


                } else {
                echo "<text style='color:red;'> You Must Specify A Message</a></text>";
                }
                }



            echo "
                <form action='' method='POST'>
            <textarea name='post_message' id='post_message' placeholder='Whats Going On?'></textarea><br> 
                   <input type='submit' name='post_message_submit' value='Post'>
                    </form>

            ";


            $fetch_index_query = $db->query("SELECT post_id,posted_by,post_body,post_active,group_name FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "groups_posts WHERE group_name='$get_group_url'");





            while($fetch_index_groups_array = $db->fetch_array($fetch_index_query)) {
            $post_id_row = $fetch_index_groups_array['post_id'];
            $posted_by = $fetch_index_groups_array['posted_by'];
            $g_name = $_fetch_index_groups_array['g_name'];
            $g_body = $fetch_index_groups_array['post_body'];
            echo("<br>" . "<a href=''> $posted_by </a>" . "<br>" . $gname
            . "<br>____________
            <br> 
            <form action='' method='POST'>
            <input type='text' name='comment_post' placeholder='Comment then Hit Enter'>
            </form>
            "
            );
            $fetch_comments_query = $db->query("SELECT g_name,post_body,comment_by FROM spud_groups_comments WHERE post_id='$post_id_row'");
            while($fetch_groups_comments = $db->fetch_array($fetch_comments_query)) {
            $post_body = $fetch_groups_comments['post_body'];




            echo ("<br>" . $post_body);



            }
            $insert_query = $db->query("INSERT INTO " . TABLE_PREFIX . "groups_posts" . "(posted_by, group_name, post_body)
            VALUES ('$mybb_username', '$get_group_url' ,'$post_message')");

            }

            //We have done everything we need to do we can now exit and not execute anything beyond this point
            exit();
            ?>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that lol I did put the query in twice for testing purposes but it did have another query to insert the comment but for some reason the fetch_array is inserting it in the database from how many comments its found (say if it's found 4 posts it will insert the comment in the database 4 times)

Thanks for trying so far ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove second insert query from code.